# Executing TFS queries and consuming the results using the TFS OData API with LINQ

Tags: linq, api, tfs, odata

In reference to the TFS OData API described at https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/

I'm building a metrics dashboard application (in C#) that needs to extract some values (story points/effort) from my client's cloud hosted TFS using the TFS OData API. I can successfully request all queries separately, and all workitems separately, but I can't seem to consume the list of workitems that is connected to a specific pre-defined TFS query.

In the ideal case, I would like to programmatically execute any pre-defined TFS query and aggregate the resulting list of WorkItems, so that I can use the TFS UI for administration of the filters  instead of having to code the filters myself (for instance if a new project should be included in the metrics). However, I can't seem to find any way of actually issue an execute command via the TFS OData API. Anybody know if it is possible to execute a TFS query and consume the results via the OData API?